# Unable to read octet stream response in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, superagent

I have an API that returns response as 'octet-stream'. Here is swagger defination for the same.

```
responses: {
  '200': {
    description: 'Will return the pdf for an invoice',
      content: {
      'application/octet-stream': {
        schema: '',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

From postman and swagger ui i am able to save the response as a PDF File. but with node i am not able to write the pdf file.

Below is code for node js to call the API.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
let headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'accept': "application/octet-stream",
}
let body = {
  "invoiceId": "343",
  "slCompId": 243,
  "platfromCompId": "4620816365013235830"
}

request.post({
  headers,
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/invoice/',
  json: body
},
  function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log("response");
    fs.writeFile('a.pdf', response.body, 'binary')
  });
```

**EDIT:**

The PDF file which is written is corrupted. There is nothing inside the file and PDF viewer gives me error in opening the file.

Comment: What does "i am not able to write the pdf file" mean?

Comment: I get response for writing the PDF file. I am not able to write.

Comment: What does "I am not able to write" mean? Are you getting an error? Is the file created but blank? It helps to be specific on Stackoverflow. Also, you're not passing the callback to writeFile, so it may be erroring and something amy be eating the error https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: The file which is written is corrupted. There is nothing inside the file and PDF viewer gives me error in opening the file.

Comment: did you try writing `body` instead of `response.body`? Also, you could use streams instead of buffering the whole file first: https://github.com/request/request#streaming. Additionally, `request` is deprecated as of today, so you're probably fine to use superagent but the point about streaming still stands.

Comment: I have found solution please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. I tried hitting the API with superagent with `buffer` as `true`.

```
async function getData() {
try  {
  var fs = require('fs');
  let res = await superagent
  .get('https://localhost:3000/invoice')
  .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .set("accept", "application/octet-stream")
  .buffer(true).disableTLSCerts()
  console.log(res)
  fs.writeFile('a.pdf',res.body)
 }

catch(error) {
  console.log("error " + error)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me but please let me know how we can define buffer:true in (node-fetch) library as I am trying to implement same using (node-fetch) but not getting irrelevant data.